# Cannot Get EJS Files to Render in HTML: What's Going Wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I can't render my EJS files as HTML. Every time I try to access my EJS file, I get a "Cannot GET /store.html" response.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').config()
}

const stripeSecretKey = process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
const stripePublicKey = process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY

const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const fs = require('fs')
const stripe = require('stripe')(stripeSecretKey)

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/store', (req, res) => {
fs.readFile('items.json', (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        res.status(500).end()
    } else {
        res.render('store.ejs', {
            items: JSON.parse(data)
        })
    }
})
})

app.listen(3000)
```

I would like to know what I should do?

Comment: Why do you try to get `store.html`? Should be `/store`, as your route defines it

Answer (score 0):

Before proceeding,check your route, `/store.html` is wrong, You should call this API like this `http://localhost:3000/store`

If it doesn't work following below:

check that you have already installed the ejs package.
You are trying to access your `ejs` file with a `.html` extension, which is not correct. You should use the same extension as the filename, such as `/store.ejs` in your `views` folder.

Change from `/store.html` to `/store.ejs`

I hope this solution helps you.